# ¿Cuál es el origen de la frase "anda a freír monos"?

Tags: refranes

What is the origin of the expression / ¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión "irse a freír monos"?

Answer (score 2):

Existen bastantes variantes y expresiones que poseen el mismo sentido y características que "**Ir a freír monos**", tales como;

- Irse a freír espárragos.
- Irse a freír churros.
- Irse a freír morcillas
- Irse a hacer puñetas.
- Irse al guano.
- Irse al carajo.
- Irse a hacer gárgaras.
- **Irse a freír monos.**
- ...

Todas tienen como valor "**mandar a paseo a alguien**", es decir, una forma coloquial de manifestar desagrado, enfado o rechazo por una persona en un momento dado y a la que le desean que se vaya lejos para realizar otra actividad o deje de molestar.

El término "**Irse a Freír Monos**" ha evolucionado desde otro término, pues proviene de la expresión, "Irse a Freír monas" o simplemente "A freír monas", y aunque se utiliza en la locución la palabra "**mona**", está voz ,**"mona**", no tiene nada que ver con el animal o primate como en un principio podría parecer.

El llamado "**hornazo o mona de Pascua**", es un tipo de pan casero que antiguamente era fabricado en los hogares y que se le entregaba en señal de agradecimiento por parte de los vecinos al cura o predicador de la Cuaresma después del Sermón de Gracias.

Actualmente es una rosca o torta guarnecida de huevos cocidos que se hacen conjuntamente en el horno de la que existen numerosas variantes.

[image]
[image]
[image]

La predisposición para realizar la masa principal, la preparación de los ingredientes, el tener que freír el aceite con la cáscara de limón, dejarla enfriar... es lo que dio lugar a "irse a freír monas", es decir, "*irse a preparar todos los condimentos y realizar todo el proceso de elaboración para hacer las monas de Pascua*", pues éste, el proceso de elaboración, suele ser lento ya que necesita muchas horas de reposo.

Está locución de "freír monas" o "irse a freír monas", es la que dio lugar o derivó hacia una mala interpretación y a un cambio de sexo del objeto origen, de "**mona**" paso a "**mono**", creyendo que "mona" era referida al primate y no a otra cosa, apareciendo entonces la expresión "**irse a freír monos**", que así dicho no deja de ser un poco espeluznante.